# Inserting byte array into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am constructing a `sql_insert_string` to be used in `Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper` to be used as follows:

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Transaction, CommandType.Text, sql_insert_string)
```

When I hover over the SQL statement it looks like below:

```
 string sql_insert_string = "Insert into images_table(image_id,     image_byte_array) values ('123', System.Byte[])
```

One of the insert value is a byte array as shown above. The variable has value in the byte array, say like byte[6738] . But after the `sql_insert_string` is constructed, it comes as `System.Byte[]`. The `image_byte_array` column type is `varbinary(max)`. The database is SQL Server 2008. Because of this the database throws the following error:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as \"\" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: Your sql string builder just call `ToString()` on your variable of type `byte[]`. Show method which create a sql query string

Comment: You shouldn't be *constructing* SQL statements - you should be using **parameters** to avoid SQL injection attacks!

Comment: `SqlParameter` not only saves you from SQL Injection, in addition you will not have such a problem, because all input values will will be properly "converted" to SqlParameters

Comment: It's not a proper sql statement you've created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can insert the byte array like so:

```
        private void FireSql(byte[] input)
        {
            const string sql_insert_string =
                "Insert into images_table(image_id, image_byte_array) values (@image_id, @image_byte_array)";

            SqlTransaction transaction = null; //wherever you get the transaction obj from.

            var imageIdParam = new SqlParameter("@image_id", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = 123
            }; //change the data type to whatever data type you are expecting

            var byteParam = new SqlParameter("@image_byte_array", SqlDbType.VarBinary)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Size = input.Length,
                Value = input
            }; //change the data type to whatever data type you are expecting

            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(transaction, CommandType.Text, sql_insert_string, imageIdParam, byteParam);
        }
```

I would suggest looking at an ORM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like Entity Framework(http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) to do all of this for you while increasing security and future changes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the **Parameters** while constructing the SQL Query which obviously will avoid SQL Injection attacks. How your queries are getting constructed is still unclear here.
Something like this should do it for you.

```
SqlParameter sParam = new SqlParameter("@image_byte_array", SqlDbType.VarBinary)
{
 Value = image
};
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Transaction, CommandType.Text, sql_insert_string, sParam)
```

Answer (score -4):

You may use

```
string sql_insert_string = 
    String.Format("INSERT INTO images_table(image_id, image_byte_array) VALUES ('123', CAST('{0}' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))", System.Byte[].ToString());
```

And yes, as @marc_s commented, you shouldn't be constructing SQL statements as a security concern.